# Why does the following while loop work with an AND, as opposed to an OR

Tags: c++, expression, boolean-logic

so I'm making a game and I just managed to fix the issue I was having by changing my OR to an AND and I'm not sure I understand why it works as opposed to the logical || I had there before.

```
    //while user doesn't press quit, hasn't crashed into a bomb or hasn't saved all bears the game continues
while (((!wantsToQuit(key)) && (hasLost == false)) && (bearsSaved !=3))
{
    if (isArrowKey(key))
    {
        updateGameData(grid, bears, bombs, detonator, exit, key, message, bearsSaved, bombsActive, moves, hasLost); //move bear in that direction
        updateGrid(grid, maze, bears, bombs, detonator, exit);  //update grid information
    }
    else if (toupper(key) == CHEAT) //pressing c enables cheat mode; disables bombs and sets the users moves to 500
    {
        cheatMode(message, moves, cheatActive, bombsActive);
    }
    else
        message = "INVALID KEY!";   //set 'Invalid key' message
    paintGame(grid, message, bearsSaved, moves); //display game info, modified grid & messages
    key = getKeyPress();            //display menu & read in next option
}
endProgram();                       //display final message
return(0);
```

The basic idea is that the user has to save 3 bears by guiding them through a maze and avoiding bombs.

- If they walk into a bomb, hasLost is set to true and thus endProgram is ran.
- If they press Q, the while loop is no longer true and endProgram is ran.
- However, if all bears are saved then the game also ends.

What I don't understand is why this while loop works whilst:

The player does not want to quit AND the player has not lost AND the player has not saved all 3 bears.

As opposed to:

The player does not want to quit AND the player has not lost OR the player has not saved all 3 bears.

To me the latter makes more sense logically speaking, since one would expect the game to continue running whilst they don't want to quit and haven't lost, or if they haven't saved all of the bears.

Thank you for clarification

Comment: Imagine the condition was "Game continues running if they haven't lost or they haven't saved the bears".  Then suppose they save the bears.  That would mean the game continues running.  "or" means one or the other or both; it's still true that they haven't lost, even after saving the bears, so the game continues.

Comment: thank you for the response @M.M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The player does not want to quit AND the player has not lost OR the player has not saved all 3 bears

In this scenario, your while-loop condition would look like:

```
while (((!wantsToQuit(key)) && (hasLost == false)) || (bearsSaved !=3))
```

Let's assume that the player has **not** lost, and he does **not** want to quit the game. Now, if your player saves 3 bears, then the `bearsSaved !=3` condition would be falsified. However, since you use the `||`, *even if the second statement is falsified, the game will continue, as the first statement is still **true**.* This goes against your logic, because you want:

> However, **if all bears are saved then the game also ends**.

With the `||` statement, you would have to falsify both conditions (I take the first 2 parenthesized conditions as one major one) in order for the loop to terminate.

That is why the logic you use right now makes sense; as soon as the user wins, the AND condition is falsified, and as soon as one AND condition is falsified, the loop terminates.

Comment: @A Busy Programmer, really appreciate the explanation. That makes perfect sense, by your logic looking at it as logic gates or 0s or 1s makes me understand it better in this case. Thank you